# Is it possible to detect if a thread or message is snoozed in the Gmail API

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I would like to use the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) to list threads in a user's inbox which have not had a label applied nor have been snoozed. It is possible to list those with no labels using (in the javascript version of their API)

```
gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
  'userId': userId,
  'q': '-has:userlabels -in:sent -in:chat -in:draft in:inbox'
})
```

However, this returns a list of messages which includes those which are snoozed. I would like to know either

A) Something to add to the query parameter which causes the result set to exclude snoozed messages.

B) An attribute of the returned message which indicates that the message has been snoozed.

C) A way to list all of the snoozed messages--I can then subtract that set.

Is this possible with the Gmail API?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

`label:pinned` is the secret sauce for discovering messages that have rejoined the inbox after their quick nap.

Adding `-label:pinned` to your above query should do the trick.

Second answer [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/69906/how-to-find-an-email-in-gmail-that-was-snoozed-in-google-inbox) was the key to this discovery.